# How to Create a Windows Notification with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification that shows up on my windows when some event fires. For example by clicking a button. I've been reading documentation over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API and I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong.

When I click Request then it comes up and I click allow and status says granted. But then I go to send a notification and nothing happens after I click Send.

```js
document.querySelector('#request').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
  console.log("This browser does not support notifications.");
  } else {
  Notification.requestPermission((p)=>document.querySelector('p > span').textContent = p);
  }
});


document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
  console.log("This browser does not support notifications.");
  } else {
  var notification = new Notification('To do list', { body: "This is some test"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="request">Request</button>
<button id="send">Send Notification</button>
<p>Status: <span></span></p>
```

Comment: Your code is too overcomplicated for a [example] - but, `Notification.permission` is read only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/randycasburn/pen/VwmrZOr?editors=1010) is what minimal example looks like. Work with that and reproduce you problem with as little code as possible.

Comment: @RandyCasburn sure, I updated.

Comment: And it works just fine - but not in the StackSnippet. If you go to codepen and put this code there you will see it works fine.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I put this in an .html file and run it on my own PC. Notification never came up

Comment: Please go to this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/randycasburn/pen/VwmrZOr?editors=1010) - clear the browser data for that web site. And then run and click the buttons. I cannot speak to your configuration or how you are running that file (`file://my.html`) etc. But the codepen should work **after you clear your browser data** for that web site.

Comment: @RandyCasburn on codepen I get denied result when I click request

Comment: Please use a different browser and try again.

Comment: @RandyCasburn same result

Comment: It seems like you have a platform specific problem (meaning your system). Some compatibility issue, ad blocker, browser privacy setting, or one of the many, many things that can prevent this from working. I can't peer into your system, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong, however you need to run it on a local server, if you are using Visual Studio Code there are several extensions that do this, I like to use the "Live Preview" which is official from Microsoft. [I tested your code on a local server and it worked perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB3D6.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).